# postman returns empty array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, postman, backend

I sent below (raw/json) from postman to mongodb and I received filled img, text but coordinates was empty array "[]"

```
{
    "coordinates": [],
    "_id": "5b309b5671903722e073827e",
    "date": "2018-06-25T07:35:50.932Z",
    "__v": 0
},
```

Why is this is and how get not empty coordinates array?

Postman

```
{
    "img": "test",
    "text": "Meet",
    "coordinates": [12, 23]
}
```

this is my schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const memoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  img: {
    type: String
  },
  text: {
    type: String
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  coordinates: [Number]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Memo', memoSchema)
```

this is my router

```
api.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  let newMemo = new Memo()
  newMemo.img = req.body.img
  newMemo.text = req.body.text
  newMemo.coordinates = req.body.coordinates

  await newMemo.save((err) => {
    if(err) return res.status(500).json({ message: 'internal error' })
    res.json({ message: 'saved...' })
  })
})
```

Comment: Are you using the `bodyParser` module? https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: Oops... I forgot bodyParser thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't add bodyparser

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())